# UTF Time for modified File IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, file-manager

Need to get the last modified time for IOS application inside the document folder with UTF time format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following code, that will help

```
+ (NSString*) fnGetModifiedTime: (NSString*)inFolderPath {

    NSFileManager* fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSDictionary* attrs = [fm attributesOfItemAtPath:inFolderPath error:nil];
    int theDirModified = 0;

    if (attrs != nil) {
        NSDate *date = (NSDate*)[attrs objectForKey: NSFileModificationDate];
        NSDate* theGlobalDate = [self toGlobalTime:date];
        theDirModified = [theGlobalDate timeIntervalSince1970];
    } 

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",theDirModified];

}


+(NSDate *) toGlobalTime:(NSDate*) inDate
{
    NSTimeZone *tz = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    NSInteger seconds = -[tz secondsFromGMTForDate: inDate];
    return [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval: seconds sinceDate: inDate];
}
```